# Multiple worker event loop groups

Tags: netty

I am trying to write a TCP server which is expected to host thousands of persistent connections (TLS), using netty 4.1.x. During performance testing, we observed that if there are a few thousand connections to the server, and then we get a burst of say another few thousand connections, these new SSL handshakes keep the worker threads busy for a long time, which causes the existing connections to start timing out. 
In all the Netty examples available on the internet, I have seen the server being bootstrapped like this:

```
 EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(); // (1)
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap(); // (2)
        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup) ...
```

I am wondering if I can use two worker groups instead of one. So, what I intend to do is to let the workerGroup (as shown above) handle the initial handshake and once that is done, I deregister the Channel from this group and register it with the secondary group (see sample code below).

```
class SwitchToSecondaryGroupHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

private final EventLoopGroup secondaryEventLoopGroup;

public SwitchToSecondaryGroupHandler(EventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup) {
    this.secondaryEventLoopGroup = eventLoopGroup;
}

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    ctx.pipeline().remove(this);
    ChannelFuture future = ctx.channel().deregister();
    future.addListener((f) -> {
        if (f.isSuccess()) {
            ChannelFuture registerFuture = secondaryEventLoopGroup.register(ctx.channel());
            registerFuture.addListener((e) -> {
                ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
            });

        }
    });
}
```

}

This handler will be added immediately after the SslHandler. It probably doesn't have to be after the channel read, it can be done just before the write as well.
This way the secondary group can keep servicing the existing connections, and any burst of new connections will not affect them. In my testing using a standalone program with StringEncoder/Decoder, it seems to work.

Are there any potential issues with this approach? By issues I mean, to the workings of netty itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory this works but reregister channels is kind of a "hacky" business which may also lead to the situation that we will at some point not support this anymore in netty. The problem here comes with the fact of ensure correctness in terms of visibility of things and execution when a channel moves from one thread to another.

I would be interested to see the profiler snapshots for the problem you described here to as this is clearly not what I would expect. Can you please open a netty issue with all the info and attach the profiler snapshot there. Thanks!