# Is re-registering a channel to a different eventloop group recommended?

Tags: netty

We have a problem where new channel bootstrap fails because the authentication requests timeout. One of the reasons these authentication requests timeout is because the worker event-loops are busy sending data on existing channel. I am considering re-registering the channel to a different eventloop group so that worker event-loops are free to serve authentication requests. My question is whether re-registeration of a channel to a different eventloop group stable? From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751058/multiple-worker-event-loop-groups) post it seems, that it is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to do the re-registering thing. Netty does the registering automatically and changing it may break the thread model.

I think the right solution is to figure out why worker event-loop is so busy as no blocking operation should be allowed in the loop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can first consider increasing the number of threads in NioEventLoopGroup, which is relatively simple. The default number of threads is NettyRuntime.availableProcessors() * 2.

```
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(nThreads);
```

If you can't solve the problem, you can consider using a separate thread pool for long tasks, like this

```
EventExecutorGroup longIOExecutorGroup = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(nThreads);
// in ChannelInitializer
socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(longIOExecutorGroup, yourLongIOHandler)
```